# Hierarchial Bayesian approaches versus simple prior based approaches

Tags: bayesian, regularization, prior, hierarchical-bayesian

The point of Hierarchical Bayesian models is that you can get parameters for different "hierarchies" within your data. For example, if you have 10 data points for one person, 10 for the next and so on, it helps you obtain a model for each person that uses the global distribution of parameters as a prior. Another thing I could do would be to first run a global model and get its parameters, and then run individual models for each person, but with a regularization term that pushes the parameters of the person close to the global parameters. This second approach seems a lot simpler to me and also seems to achieve a very similar effect. It is certainly a lot faster than the Hierarchical Bayesian model. Does anyone have more insight into the pros and cons?

Comment: How do you determine the type and amount of regularization? In a hierarchical Bayesian approach the type is determined by distributional assumptions and the data determines the amount.

Comment: Let's say I go with L2 and the amount is based on intuition/ can be tuned with hit and trial. Doesn't seem like too big a deal. Is that the only advantage HB provides?

Comment: The parameters at the global level are different in the two cases.  In the first, they are parameters of the distribution of the lower level parameters.  In the second, since you aren't estimating at the lower level, you can't get estimates of the parameters of the distribution of the lower level parameters - that whole level of detail is invisible to you.